# Laravel collection result format change got so many errors to the following format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-api

Here i am using a Laravel php Api for fetching data and to transfer to angular Project.Need help with formatting laravel collection.is it possible to do like this?

Current Output:
Input:-

```
"data": [
            {
                "ID": "1",
                "JobFamilyID": "1",
                "JobFamilyCode": "BA",
                "JobFamilyName": "Business And Administrative Services",
                "MajorGroupID": "2",
              
            },]

  [
            {
                "ID": "",
                "JobFamilyID": "",
                "JobFamilyCode": "BA",
                "JobFamilyName": "Business And Administrative Services",
                "MajorGroupID": "2",
              
            },]
```

expected output;-

```
{

 "JobFamilyId": "1",

 "JobFamilyName": "Business And Administrative Services",
      
},
{

"JobFamilyId": "2",

"JobFamilyName": "Educational Service",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return response()->json([
  'data' => $yourCollection
])
```

You must return your response as Json into an array.

something like this :

your output is incorrect you must return something like this :

```
"data": [
            {
               "ID": "1",
                "JobFamilyID": "",
                "JobFamilyCode": "BA",
                "JobFamilyName": "Business And Administrative Services",
                "MajorGroupID": "1",
            },
            {
                "ID": "2",
                "JobFamilyID": "",
                "JobFamilyCode": "BA",
                "JobFamilyName": "Business And Administrative Services",
                "MajorGroupID": "2",
              
            }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . i tried not getting

Comment: will check and inform you

Comment: If you don't get the answer, send me your code.

Comment: return $this->successResponse($hierarchyAndStructures,'Data retrieved succesfully',200);